# Prioritizing goroutine in golang

Tags: go, server, load, goroutine, low-latency

I'm writing a low latency network, high throughput server in golang. It has acceptor in the main goroutine (which accepts incoming connections). And it passes the incoming connections to 'n' number of worker goroutines.

In this case, to not drop connections, I want the acceptor goroutine to be prioritized over other goroutines so that connections won't be dropped. Or atleast this acceptor goroutine should not get evicted by other worker goroutines.

How can I ensure this?

Comment: You can't. All goroutines have equal priority.

Comment: You can lock a goroutine to its underlying OS thread with `runtime.LockOSThread` (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LockOSThread) but that still doesn't get you *priority* and actually wastes an OS thread because it will spend the vast majority of its time blocked waiting for an incoming connection.

Comment: Even if you could, that's not generally a good architecture for a high throughput server, as large bursts would overwhelm the system. The OS syn backlog buffers the incoming connections, preventing you from having to service them immediately, so having the accept loop handle extra connections without workers to service them doesn't really buy you much.

Comment: @JimB I didn't say that workers won't run. All I'm saying is that acceptor shouldn't get evicted. It should continuously run. The workers can maintain queue to process at their pace. We can have high number of workers. I don't understand how this is not a good architecture, when we've nginx working on the same model.

Comment: @Adrian Would locking to a thread, ensure that the goroutine won't get evicted? That's my concern. If multiple goroutines get scheduled to the same thread, then it's not helpful.

Comment: @viji, but what you’re describing is what the OS already does for you. Until you have benchmarks that show the accept thread is a bottleneck (which is also separate from the poller itself), this seems like solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @Adrian I'm talking about a system where we receive 40k+ connections every second. Acceptor definitely has a problem since we've lots of syn flooding message, when acceptor backlog is low, and high latency when acceptor backlog is high. The workers are doing pretty which have latency < 1 ms. But the overall latency is increased to more than 100ms, when the acceptor backlog is high.

Comment: Also, we dont' see this problem when I run multiple processes accepting connections and workers processing them. However, the cache is not shared which is why this model is not very useful.

Comment: If you could do this in multiple processes, you could do it in a single process. Just run multiple listeners. It means each has to have a different port or interface, but the same is true of multiple processes so clearly that's not an issue for you.

Comment: That's true. In multiple processes, every process has an acceptor and workers (workers are in thousand). Whereas without this, multiple acceptor goroutines may end up in same thread as well, which is not the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created threadpools on golang. This should allow easily one to prioritize certain goroutines over others.

https://github.com/vijayviji/executor

Answer (score -1):

If you prioritize accepting connections over "doing the work", consider what happens over time.  You will create a backlog of work, while accepting more and more connections, bringing even more work to be done.  This just makes the load on your server higher.

Instead, focus on writing your worker code to be very efficient, so that the work will be completed quickly, freeing up resources to handle new connections.

If you are concerned about your server being unable to handle the workload, you should think about rate-limiting your clients.

Comment: Actually, this is a rate limiting server. The case is for bursty workloads. When there's a burst of requests, I don't want to drop them, just because the workers were processing and they evicted the acceptor.